# Adding a Monoid constraint to a hidden variable

Tags: haskell, applicative, monoids

I'm in the Haskell Book chapter on `Applicative`. I am writing the `Applicative` instance for `ZipList` and I know I overthought it and am changing my approach. My old approach was:

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a) deriving (Eq, Show)

newtype ZipList' a =
    ZipList' (List a)
    deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Applicative ZipList' where
    pure a = ZipList' (Cons a Nil)
    ZipList' Nil <*> _ = ZipList' Nil
    _ <*> ZipList' Nil = ZipList' Nil
    (ZipList' (Cons a bs)) <*> (ZipList' (Cons a' bs')) = (ZipList' (Cons (a(a')) Nil)) `mappend` (ZipList' bs <*> ZipList' bs')
```

I get the error:

```
 No instance for (Monoid b) arising from a use of ‘mappend’
      Possible fix:
        add (Monoid b) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            (<*>) :: forall a b. ZipList' (a -> b) -> ZipList' a -> ZipList' b
    • In the expression:
        (ZipList' (Cons (a (a')) Nil))
          `mappend` (ZipList' bs <*> ZipList' bs')
      In an equation for ‘<*>’:
          (ZipList' (Cons a bs)) <*> (ZipList' (Cons a' bs'))
            = (ZipList' (Cons (a (a')) Nil))
                `mappend` (ZipList' bs <*> ZipList' bs')
      In the instance declaration for ‘Applicative ZipList'’
```

I think this is because the `mappend` uses the `Monoid` for `ZipList` which is:

```
instance Monoid a => Monoid (ZipList' a) where
    mempty = pure mempty
    mappend = liftA2 mappend
```

which places a `Monoid` constraint on the `a`. In the `Applicative` instance I can't add the `a` to the class instance without it ceasing to be a proper `Applicative` instance definition. I know that the solution is incorrect, but it did make me think "How would I add a `Monoid` constraint to the argument to `ZipList` in the `Applicative` instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to append anything here. Don't build a list `Cons x Nil` and append list `y`, just build `Cons x y`.

```
let ZipList bs'' = ZipList' bs <*> ZipList' bs'
in ZipList' (Cons (a a') bs'')
```

About the monoid-related error. It depends on which instance you are using for your type `ZipList'`.

If you use something like

```
instance Monoid (ZipList' a) where
   mempty = ZipList' Nil
   mappend (ZipList' Nil) zs = zs
   mappend (ZipList' (Cons x xs)) zs = let
      ZipList' ys = mappend (Ziplist' xs) zs
      in ZipList' (Cons x ys)
```

then there is no need for `Monoid a`.

I think it all depends on what kind of monoid you want. The `Monoid (ZipList' a)` you mentioned appends each component of the two lists in a pointwise fashion, and for that we do need `Monoid a`. However, in the applicative instance you do not need that kind of append, you need list concatenation. This could be achieved using the above monoid instance, instead.

That being said: the instance you posted, working pointwise, is probably the most natural for `ZipList`. Nothing however stops you to define a non-instance function

```
appendZipList' :: ZipList' a -> ZipList' a -> ZipList' a
```

and use that in your applicative instance, without relying on monoids.

Otherwise, you could define `instance Monoid (List a)` for the concatenating append, and use that in the applicative instance

```
let ZipList' bs'' = ZipList' bs <*> ZipList' bs'
in ZipList' (Cons (a a') Nil `mappend` bs'')
```

Comment: I ended up with some non-instance functions to zip the list and then throw that result into a `ZipList'`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up eliminating the Monoid requirement and using a function on Lists which walked them and applied the funcs from the left to the values on the right.

```
zipForMyList :: List (t -> a) -> List t -> List a
zipForMyList _ Nil                   = Nil
zipForMyList Nil _                   = Nil
zipForMyList (Cons f fs) (Cons a as) = (Cons (f a) (zipForMyList fs as))

repeatMyList :: p -> List p
repeatMyList x = xs where xs = Cons x xs

instance Applicative ZipList' where
    pure a = ZipList' (Cons a Nil)
    ZipList' Nil <*> _ = ZipList' Nil
    _ <*> ZipList' Nil = ZipList' Nil
    (ZipList' fs) <*> (ZipList' as) = ZipList' (zipForMyList fs as)
```